# Error in R: incorrect number of subscripts on matrix

Tags: r

I have a dataset, and I am trying to make another dataset that is based on the previous dataset. Obviously, I will use a for loop to do that!

Below is the data set used, and represented by the variable `data`.

[image: data]

So I want to use rows 1 to 501 and columns 3,4,5,6 to make the new data set. Hence, I wrote the following code:

```
n <- nrow(data)
scenarios <- array(c(0), c(n-1,4))
for (j in 3:6) {
  for (i in 2:n) {
    scenarios[i-1, j-2] = data[i, j] / data[i-1, j] * data[n, j] 
  }
}
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> Error in scenarios[i - 1, j - 2] <- data[i, j]/data[i - 1, j] * data[n,  :
> incorrect number of subscripts on matrix

Any clue about what is going on? I appreciate your help!

Comment: Is the intention to get a new data set where each cell reflects an index's growth over the prior observation, multiplied by the last value? I'd use `library(dplyr); scenarios <- data %>% mutate(across(1:5, ~.x / lag(.x) * last(.x)))`

Comment: Can you explain what does "1:5" represents here?

Comment: Oh sorry, that was what I used on my test data. Replace with whichever column numbers (or names) you want to apply the calculation to.

Comment: "Obviously, I will use a for loop to do that!" Note that in R, vectorized solutions are preferred in many cases where you’d use a loop in another language. e.g., in Python where you might use `[val * 2 for val in vals]`, in R you’d simply use `vals * 2`. Loops have their uses in R, but aren’t the go-to option nearly as much as in other languages.